# Binary Array Function Solution

Tags: python, binary-data

A function that takes a binary array as input and finds out the maximum no. of zeroes present in the array after applying only one operation in which we can flip the elements of a subarray i.e. changing 0 to 1 and vice versa.

Can someone write the program in python considering all the edge cases.

I tried using chatgpt and other AI but could solve some of the hidden test cases and I can't think of a test cases which might be failing.

Some example test cases are:
Input : [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 ]
Output : 6

Input : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
Output : 5

I need help in creating the complete function which takes the binary array input and return the output.

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Comment: I think this is supposed to be question and answer website. I don't think unpaid work requests are OK here.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I don't think asking for help in a DSA question is unpaid work , I am not asking you to build a website or something for me.

Comment: @AyushVerma "Can someone write the program in python considering all the edge cases." Sounds like it. But what do I know? You got an answer, so apparently I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick is to find the longest subarray containing ones and flipping its values then counting the zeros.

```
def foo(list1):
    # first search for the longest subarray containing ones
    start_index=0 # start index of the longest subarray
    length=0 # number of elements it contains
    
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        
        if list1[i]==1: # we have found a one, check how many ones come after it
            
            j=i
            temp_length=0
    
            while  j<len(list1) and list1[j]==1:
                j+=1
                temp_length+=1
            if temp_length>length:
                start_index=i
                length=temp_length

    # flip the values in that subarray to zeros
    list1[start_index:start_index+length]=[0]*length

    # return the count of zeros
    return list1.count(0)
```